# {Mysql2::Error} Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 when use mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

here is my [full sql](https://gist.github.com/078bad8df23fcfd9e27c), I try following code and raise `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 when use mysql2`

```
conf = {adapter: "mysql2", host: "localhost", username: "root", password: "root", database: 'ro_article_prod', port: 3306, encoding: 'utf8mb4', flags: (Mysql2::Client::FOUND_ROWS | Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS), encoding: 'utf8', checkout_timeout: 1.day, connect_timeout: 1.hour, reconnect: true, pool: 2000}
m = Mysql2::Client.new(conf)
m.query(RoFile.read("chk/val.sql"));
m.abandon_results!
```

but when I run following code in mysql shell, it work and not raise any error

```
insert articles (title, url, ctn, ctn_md5, created_at, updated_at) values("Amy (Character)  - Quotes", "http:/www.imdb.com/character/ch0052152/quotes", "", "", "2016-01-05 07:12:55", "2016-01-05 07:12:55");
insert articles (title, url, ctn, ctn_md5, created_at, updated_at) values("Amy (Character)", "http:/www.imdb.com/character/ch0052152/maindetails", "", "", "2016-01-05 07:12:55", "2016-01-05 07:12:55");
insert articles (title, url, ctn, ctn_md5, created_at, updated_at) values("Amy (Character)  - Filmography by type", "http:/www.imdb.com/character/ch0052152/filmotype", "", "", "2016-01-05 07:12:55", "2016-01-05 07:12:55");
```

Comment: I suggest you add you table structure as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the full SQL you linked to, all of the rows have six columns, but one of them has five values. Here's the incorrect one:

```
insert articles (title, url, ctn, ctn_md5, created_at, updated_at) values("Trudy Chelgren (Character)  - Filmography by rating", "http:/www.imdb.com/character/ch0052168/filmorate", "", "2016-01-05 07:12:55", "2016-01-05 07:12:55");
```